# Can I 'double' dip into a baseline to both reduce variance, and use it as a level of my with factor of time?

Tags: anova, post-hoc, ancova

I have a bit of a situation I would like some advice on.

I'm currently running a human subjects study where I have two groups (group 1 and group 2), and three time points. Each subject performs a repetitive task at the same rate, with a slight difference between the groups.

I take a baseline, an early time measure (after about a minute), and then a late time measure. All three measurements in time are experimentally identical. If I used the baseline either as a regression term in an ANCOVA or to "correct" a subject's subsequent measurements I get two main strong main effects, for group and for time (number of repetitions of a task). However, I get no interaction effect.

Yet, if I run post-hoc t-tests (which I believe I'm not 'allowed' to do based on the lack of an interaction effect) between the two early time points for each group I get strong significance (p = 0.001). The baseline data are not different between groups. This makes me believe that I do have an interaction effect with time (number of repetitions). The interaction plot looks likes this:

[image]

Just looking at the data, it appears that the difference between the groups is mostly a result of an early "boost" one of the groups gets in time. Group 1 appears to change between baseline and the earliest time point, and Group 2 does not. However, both groups change equally from time point 2 to time point 3.

Indeed, if I run a 2x3 Mixed ANOVA I get an interaction effect, once I include baseline as a time point. However, because I've now no longer corrected/regressed out the baseline my once quite strong main effect (p<0.001) now disappears because of immense baseline variability.

My question then becomes, am I justified in both using my baseline data as a regressor to remove variability AND a level for my time factor? Somehow this feels like double dipping to me. However, in my mind this would better represent what I see in the data.

Am I allowed to do this? Or does anyone have any other suggestions? Thanks!